# Bootstrapping WaldTest?

Tags: r, bootstrap

I recently came across a paper that bootstraps p-values for an (M)Wald test. The authors do it, because they had small samples. If correct, researchers call this approach the "residual-based bootstrap (RBB) method".

Source:
http://www.econjournals.com/index.php/ijefi/article/viewFile/1758/pdf

I'm little lost in building such a bootstrap. For now, I apply the Toda and Yamamoto (1995) test and my script returns correct p-values.

now I wonder how to "bootstrap" the p-value. I wish I could describe my question more precisely, but I could not find any R code that seems to go into the direction. Only found this here:

http://www.statmethods.net/advstats/bootstrapping.html